# Error during React Native IOS in-app product purchase test [Error: Invalid product ID.]

Tags: in-app-purchase

---

Hello, you are trying to test in-app purchases for your `iOS` app but encountered an error during the testing process.

You have completed the following steps:

```
1. Created an Apple Developer account.
2. Added the app to App Store Connect and enabled in-app purchases.
3. Created a test account and added it to the "Tester" list.
4. Created test in-app purchase items by selecting "In-App Purchases" and clicking "Create".
5. Written code to call in-app purchases in the app using "react-native-iap@9.0.0".
6. This error occurred during the in-app purchase test after product registration
```

The code I'm currently using:

```
//jsx


  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    clearProductsIOS(); 
    initConnection(); 
    const productIds = ['com.celeb.example1.product','com.celeb.example2.product','com.celeb.example3.product'];
    getProducts(productIds).then((products) => {
      console.log('products:', products);
      setProducts(products);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('error:', error);
      console.log(iap.products);
    });
  }, []);

  const handlePress = (productId) => {
    requestPurchase(productId).then((purchase) => {
      console.log('purchase:', purchase);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('error:', error);
    });
  };


  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      {products.map((product) => (
        <View key={product.productId}>
          <Text style={styles.productPrice}>{product.localizedPrice}</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handlePress(product.productId)}>
            <Text>Purchase</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
)


...
```

If you click "`handlePress`() here, you will get this error

```
error: [Error: Invalid product ID.]
```